# OpenCv Java CvKNearest usage

Tags: java, opencv

I am writing a Java application what does feature matching with OpenCV 2.4.10.
The inputs of the program are two images and now the program searches the matching keypoints of the two images with SURF algorythm.

My problem is I cannot filter the good matches. I read that the K-Nearest neighbour algorythm is the solution of my problem and there is an implementation in the OpenCV library. I found some example code with Google but these examples are written in C and the C interface of this feature is different from the Java interface.

Can anyone show me an example for this feature?
How can I use the CvKNearest.train() and the CvKNearest.find_nearest() functions in Java?

Answer (score 0):

i once used open cv 3.0 version and that was for a small application and
i never wanted to implement c methods ,, 
bt see the article maybe this could help to call  c methods in java
http://cs-people.bu.edu/dgurari/OpenCVwithJava.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There is Java wrapper for these functions what I want to use but there is not a proper description for them.
I do not know what is the meaning of the input parameters, how can I initalize the result object correctly, etc.

I do not know the correct usage even if I call the C methods directly.